# MySQL NodeJS - How do I verify that my connection pool is actually online?

Tags: mysql, node.js

So I have a simple NodeJS bot that makes use of MySQL to store data.

I initialize mysql by using the `createPool` function.

I find that this works fine, even if my server is dead. I can run it and no errors are fired, but when I run any code that uses a query on the server, *then* it will fire errors if the server is off.

I want to simplify this by simply forcing a message / error if the bot is started and the server is not online.

This is the code that I have setup so far. Ignore the dotenv stuff, its just to keep my login / database info out of the code.

```js
const mysql = require("mysql");
const path = require('path');
const envconfpath = path.join(__dirname, './.env');
require('dotenv').config({ path: envconfpath });
const connectionPool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 999,
    host: process.env.HOSTNAME, database: process.env.DATABASE,
    user: process.env.USERNAME, password: process.env.PASSWORD
});

// This is the code that does not function.

connectionPool.getConnection((err, con) => {
    if (err) 
        console.warn(`Databased failed to start with error: ${err}`);
    if(con.state === 'disconnected')
        console.log(`Database connection failed. Check that its running and that your configuration is correct`);
    else 
        console.log('Database connection successful');
});
```

Now, I do want to clear up any possible misunderstanding, **I can use my database fine**, I simply want to fire an error on initial run if the database's server is not online.

The bottom of that code that gets the connection and runs checks seems to always fire an error. Ive tried various methods for checking whether the server was online, but the code above was made by using examples **from the mysql / nodejs documentation**

This is the error that it fires, which makes no sense. If the pool is valid (which it is) the `getConnection` function (which is used on the module's documentation) should return a connection just fine. It says that the `state` of the connection is invalid, yet I can query the connection fine in other parts of the code outside of the small part I pasted in here.

As for the ACCESS DENIED part? No clue. I run the database both remotely and locally, Ive verified that both worked, and during testing, I dont use a password. This is a completely open database running locally on my system, so I dont see why it would have access issues.

```
Databased failed to start with error: Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'USER'@'HOST' (using password: NO)
----- UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION -----
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#ping ?

Comment: show the other parts of the code that can query the connection fine?